# Logo not appearing in Wordpress using SALON theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

For some reason the logo image I have uploaded into the WP theme is not pulling through to the front-end.

I have asked the theme developers multiple times and I haven't had a reply in 2 months and my client is highly frustrated as am I!!!!

You can see the CSS and HTML Below

```css
logo {
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
}

#logo {
    font-family: "raleway";
    color: #4d4b4b;
}

#logo-default {
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
    <img href="http://cardiffcosmeticacupuncture.com" id="logo">
      <img id="logo-default" src=http://cardiffcosmeticacupuncture.com/wp-content/uploads/CCA_LogoMain.png" data-src=http://cardiffcosmeticacupuncture.com/wp-content/uploads/CCA_LogoMain.png" alt="logo" />
    </img>
</div>
```

Comment: learn about `img` in html:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: and use `.logo` in css if you want to style the class or `#logo` in css if you want to style the id

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML like this. You cannot have nested images.

```css
.logo {
  z-index: 3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

#logo {
  font-family: "raleway";
  color: #4d4b4b;
}

#logo-default {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img id="logo-default" src=http://cardiffcosmeticacupuncture.com/wp-content/uploads/CCA_LogoMain.png " data-src=http://cardiffcosmeticacupuncture.com/wp-content/uploads/CCA_LogoMain.png" alt="logo/>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `logo` in css do you mean `.logo `??

Comment: Good catch! Code is adjusted.

Comment: and there is not `id="logo"`  so in css not `#` and please add explain to other users to understand your answer :)

Comment: @DharmeshVekariya Please do not change authors' code. If you think it can be improved, leave a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

`logo {` should be `.logo {`

Your image tag need to be closed properly: `<img src="..." />`

Is the website running under SSL? Maybe you should change the http to https

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace your theme code with my updated code,

```html
<div class="logo">
    <a href="http://cardiffcosmeticacupuncture.com" id="logo">
      <img id="logo-default" src="http://cardiffcosmeticacupuncture.com/wp-content/uploads/CCA_LogoMain.png" data-src="http://cardiffcosmeticacupuncture.com/wp-content/uploads/CCA_LogoMain.png" alt="logo />
    </a>
 </div>
```